# Dúvida SQL LEFT JOIN em uma tabela com valores nulos

Tags: sql, join, null, powerbi

Atualmente executo uma query que retorna um grupo de dados utilizado depois em um report do power bi.

O que eu preciso é filtrar todos os registros que tenham a coluna Status **A ou B**, além desses resultados existem registros com essas colunas com Status **Nulo, D ou E**.

Pra buscar essa informação preciso de três tabelas, a tabela EC (tabela que nos retorna a chave principal dos registros), a tabela OV e a tabela OVI(essa terceira é a que provê esse status)

tab.EC - relaciona - tab.OV

tab.OV - relaciona - tab.OVI

Eu preciso trazer esse status como uma coluna para tratar no meu report, ou já na query tratar essa informação para ignorar os status A e B.
Tentei fazer da forma abaixo selecionando o código do escritório (que é a nossa relação com a tabela dos registros principais) e pegando a data máxima do registro da EC. O problema é que como é um LEFT JOIN depois de filtrado esse select, ele trata como NULL os registros que eram A ou B, e isso fica errado no resultado final para o objetivo da query porque precisamos também dos registros que originalmente eram NULL (alguns registros como mencionei acima tem o valor nulo realmente e devem ser considerados dessa forma).

Também já tentei agrupar pelo campo de Status, mas quando faço isso gera uma duplicidade em casos onde um item do EC já teve mais de um status registrado em relação com as tabelas OV e OVI.

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT OISIDCLO, 
                  Max(OITOPEDT) AS OITOPEDT
                  FROM   [DATABASE].OISSAOHT OV
                         LEFT JOIN [DATABASE].OITSAOIT OVI
                                ON OV.OISIDSOH = OVI.OITIDSOH 
                                WHERE OVI.OITLCSTA != 'A' OR OVI.OITLCSTA != 'B'
                  GROUP  BY OISIDCLO) OV
              ON EC.OFDIDESC = OV.OISIDCLO
```

Edit:
Hoje eu fiz um teste especificando para pegar os nulos dentro da subquery, ainda não validei totalmente, mas tive um resultado diferente, estou atualizando a pergunta porque ainda não resolvi o problema, mas pode ser um caminho.

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT OISIDCLO, 
                  Max(OITOPEDT) AS OITOPEDT
                  FROM   [DATABASE].OISSAOHT OV
                         LEFT JOIN [DATABASE].OITSAOIT OVI
                                ON OV.OISIDSOH = OVI.OITIDSOH 
                                **WHERE (
                                         OVI.OITLCSTA is null 
                                      OR OVI.OITLCSTA != 'A' 
                                      OR OVI.OITLCSTA != 'B'
                                      )**
                  GROUP  BY OISIDCLO) OV
              ON EC.OFDIDESC = OV.OISIDCLO
```

Edit2: Essa opção de is null, funcionou pra mim, o problema agora é em outro filtro, mas não tem relação com esse problema! Agradeço quem conseguiu enviar respostas, e quem teve tempo de ler aqui pra tentar me ajudar.

Comment: subquery em joins não são uma coisa boa na maioria das vezes (principalmente quando você está tratando um grande volume de dados)... pode postar um link com meia dúzia de dados simulados das tabelas das quais a sua query depende? não ficou claro na sua descrição

Comment: Olá, Rhubenni, realmente, essa query está sendo meio que um quebra galho, estamos em trabalho de refatorar isso e colocar em views separadas. Infelizmente não consigo, tem algumas informações sensíveis.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Olá, você está colocando esse "filtro" como um argumento do LEFT JOIN dessa forma, quando o status for "A" ou "B" ele retornará como *NULL*. Para ignorar esses status você deve fazer isso na cláusula WHERE:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT OISIDCLO, 
              Max(OITOPEDT) AS OITOPEDT
              FROM   [DATABASE].OISSAOHT OV
                     LEFT JOIN [DATABASE].OITSAOIT OVI
                            ON OV.OISIDSOH = OVI.OITIDSOH 
              WHERE OVI.OITLCSTA != 'A' 
              AND OVI.OITLCSTA != 'B'
              GROUP  BY OISIDCLO) OV
          ON EC.OFDIDESC = OV.OISIDCLO
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Boa tarde Victor! Muito obrigado pela atenção meu caro. Realmente esse filtro que eu postei está dentro do LEFT JOIN, mas eu até cheguei a fazer o teste colocando a cláusula WHERE, mas surtiu o mesmo efeito no final.